# What are the Linux generic headers and drivers in the Ubuntu base updates?

Tags: drivers, kernel, updates, lts

From time to time an Ubuntu base update will become available that changes Linux headers, drivers etc.

I know these related to the kernel, but being on LTS I'm not sure what actually changes.

Are these backports of various improvements to the kernel? What do the headers contain, and are they in any way related to C header files?

Comment: LTS doesn't mean that your software versions are fixed, it only means that the Ubuntu release will be supported and supplied with (at least security) updates for 5 years instead of the normal 9 months.

Comment: @ByteCommander, I was assuming that the kernel version stays the same though.

Comment: The major version stays unless you instal HWE stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From time to time Linux kernel is updated in Ubuntu. When it happens, you get updates for Linux image and headers.

The image is a kernel binary file, that contains the kernel itself. The headers is a part of the kernel source code (written in C), that allows to build kernel modules against the specific kernel. The headers contain mostly procedure declarations. These are C header files.

Minor kernel updates include bug fixes and support for some new hardware.

Comment: And the binary contains the implementations of the headers?

Comment: @Bar Sure it does.